# Why my rust function get an " returns a value referencing data owned by the current function" error?

Tags: rust

I know I can't return a borrowed value from a function, but I don't know how to solve it. This is my function:

```rust
pub fn query(&self, sql: &str, params: &[&dyn ToSql]) -> Result<ResultSet<Row>, Error> {
    let pool = self.pool.clone();
    let con = pool.get().unwrap();
    let rows = con.query(sql, params).unwrap();
    Ok(rows)
}
```

this is error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `con`
  --> BloodTranslate\src\my_db\oracle_mod.rs:62:9
   |
61 |         let rows = con.query(sql,params).unwrap();
   |                    --- `con` is borrowed here
62 |         Ok(rows)
   |         ^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: r2d2_oracle and oracle crate.

Comment: I try use```let con = self.pool.get().unwrap();```,is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ResultSet` has a full type `ResultSet<'a, Row>`, so you simply cannot return it due to bound to lifetime `'a`. But you can convert it into an owned type you like, e.g. a vector:

```rust
pub fn query(&self, sql: &str, params: &[&dyn ToSql]) -> Result<Vec<Row>, Error> {
    let pool = self.pool.clone();
    let con = pool.get().unwrap();
    let rows = con.query(sql, params).unwrap();
    rows.into_iter().collect()
}
```

Note, that there's additional allocation involved and maybe redundant if you need only a single row for example.

Comment: Thanks,I am new for rust.And i try you answer,but it not work. this is error ```value of type `Vec<r2d2_oracle::oracle::Row>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::result::Result<r2d2_oracle::oracle::Row, r2d2_oracle::oracle::Error>>```

Comment: Oh, my bad, haven't notice the `ResultSet::into_iter` actually iterates over `Result`-s, not `Row`-. Give me a moment and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your support very much.